# Can we ask about educational materiels?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can I ask if anybody has reccomendations on how to learn something on stack overflow? I wonder because I want to ask about learning resources for algorithms.

Comment: Did you check the "What topics can I ask about here?" page in the help center?

Comment: Learning about algorithms might be on topic on [cs.se]. If you are a teacher, rather than a learner perhaps [cseducators.se] might also be suitable.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely off-topic. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states:

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**
>
> - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.